# Как может быть deadlock для выборки из базы?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, entity-framework, deadlock

Разбираюсь в не своем коде, там много обращений в БД(MS SQL SERVER) с использованием generic репозитория и много очень запутанного кода(поэтому его демонстрации не будет).

Бывает такое что при работе вылетает exception deadlock на методе выборки из базы.

Если упростить описание этого процесса, то для выборки из `DbSet<TEntity>`  применяются данные методы :

```
IQueryable.OrderByDescending
Queryable.Where   
Queryable.Skip  
QueryableExtensions.Include
```

До и после этой выборки, но до применения общего `context.SaveChanges` могут происходить любые Update Insert Delete Select в любых количествах.

Искал как может происходить deadlock и находил только описание случая с 2 транзакциями на [Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774935/what-is-deadlock-in-a-database) которые блокируют ресурсы друг друга. 
Но в случае с Select не понимаю как такое может произойти. Буду рад примеру такой ситуации.

Не очень разбираюсь, но возможно изолированность [транзакций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9) как то может влиять на это. Или может это проблемы на стороне c#, а не базы.

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionExce
    ption: An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. Se
    e the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Tran
    saction (Process ID 106) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process a
    nd has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolea
    n breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception
    , Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObj
    ect stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand
     cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler,
    TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Bo
    olean& more)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead
    ()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.HandleRea
    derException(Exception e)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead
    ()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnu
    merator.MoveNext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: Приложите к запросу deadlock XML report

Comment: Если SQL достаточно современный, то можно поставить [SQL Server First Responder  Kit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit) и посмотреть `sp_BlitzLock;` блокировки на сервере, сколько их там вообще.

Comment: Примерно треть всех запросов заканчиваются таким deadlock exception.

Comment: Этот exception говорит только о том что был дедлок, больше никакой полезной информации он не несет. Если нужно выяснить причину, нужен deadlock XML report. Его можно раздобыть в Extended Events-сессии system_health, если нет специальной созданной сессии для отлова дедлоков

Comment: Если нагрузить базу insert-ами или лучше update-ами - deathlock без проблем можно получить. Если с базой работаете долго - вспоминайте что менялось. Если нет - анализируйте ошибку.

Comment: nick_n_a, а как такая нагрузка на базу может вызвать deadlock в select? буду рад ссылке для того что бы познакомиться с таким положением дел.

Comment: Как написали коллеги выше, нужен детальный лог. Можно попробовать поймать профилировщиком. 
Чаще всего возникает при интенсивной многопоточной insert/update.
Вам должна помочь работа с уровнями изоляции транзакций. например IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted

Comment: AndreyMagnificent, вот ссылка, пожалуйста, можно познакомится с таким положением дел: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21767/why-are-there-victimless-entries-on-the-deadlock-graph

Comment: _"До и после этой выборки, но до применения общего context.SaveChanges могут происходить любые Update Insert Delete Select в любых количествах."_ это что же, всё в одной транзакции происходит? Если да, то не удивительно. _"Но в случае с Select не понимаю как такое может произойти."_ очень просто - например, две параллельных транзакции, 1я изменила (update) запись A, 2я - запись Б (в одной таблице), после чего 1я начинает читать (select) запись Б, а 2я - А, voilà.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Deadlock вполне может возникнуть при SELECT. На самом деле для возникновения дедлока неважна конкретная операция. Важен сам факт установки блокировки, который вызывает Deadlock.

Сильно упрощенный пример::

По умолчанию SELECT ставит S-локи. UPDATE - ставит X-локи.
[S и X-локи несовместимы](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172925%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - их нельзя одновременно поставить на один и тот же объект. Тот, кто попытается поставить лок вторым, будет ждать, пока первый его снимет.

У вас одновременно выполняются две транзакции:

1. Транзакция 1 ставит X-лок на объект A (`UPDATE A...`)
2. Транзакция 2 ставит X-лок на объект B (`UPDATE B...`)
3. Транзакция 1 пытается поставить S-лок на объект B (`SELECT FROM B...`). Ждет, пока будет снят существующий лок от транзакции 2.
4. Транзакция 2 пытается поставить S-лок на объект A (`SELECT FROM A...`). Ждет, пока будет снят существующий лок от транзакции 1.
5. В (4) SQL Server понимает, что транзакции ждут друг друга, и убивает одну из них как deadlock victim.

Пример очень сильно упрощен, гранулярность локов может быть разная (строка, таблица, страница и т.д.), SQL Server умеет повышать гранулярность вверх. Но общая картина все равно та же.

Стандартный способ избежать дедлоков на чтении - перейти на уровень изоляции транзакций, в котором SELECT не ставит локи. Это или SNAPSHOT, или READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT.

Эти уровни изоляции транзакций используют row versioning вместо блокировок, и SELECT-ы при них читают копию данных, если к моменту чтения есть незакомитанные изменения другой транзакции.

[Разница между ними - в обработке записи](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms188277(v=sql.105)). READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT ведет себя как обычный READ COMMITTED, и просто ставит U/X локи. SNAPSHOT пишет в копию, и падает на коммите транзакции, если кто-то уже успел записать до него.

Если у вас уже используется READ COMMITTED (он почти всегда и везде используется по умолчанию), то достаточно просто включить READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT на уровне базы, и дедлоки пропадут:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase  
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON  

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase  
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

---

Отдельно стоит упомянуть работу с транзакциями через TransactionScope. Этот замечательный класс по умолчанию переписывает стандартный для EF и SQL Server уровень READ COMMITTED на SERIALIZABLE, что почти гарантирует дедлоки. Если пользуетесь им - не забывайте вручную выставлять нужный вам уровень изоляции в конструкторе.

Comment: Вот за это спасибо, однозначно плюсую, очень познавательно