# Как проводить анализ deadlock графа?

Tags: sql, база-данных, .net, sql-server, многопоточность

Ранее задавал связанный с этим [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918586/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-deadlock-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B). Запустил профайлер - получил [граф](http://prntscr.com/lx2xo9) дедлока. [Вывод профайлера](http://prntscr.com/lx311d).
Тут всего 1 таблица.

Возникли вопросы:

1) Почему у крайних ресурсов(правый и левый прямоугольники) один page ID и associated objid(не знаю что это), а они отображаются разными нодами в графе?
Увидел зачеркнутую транзакцию - предположил что ее убил SQL Server. Вопрос возник потому что если рассматривать эти 2 ресурса как разные ресурсы - не понятно почему грохнули именно ту транзакцию . Читал что транзакции которые принимают участие в дедлоке - это те которые находиться в цикле графа, а зачеркнутая транзакция таковой не являться.

2) Какие подходы можно использовать для того что бы проанализировать этот граф и понять проблему?

Вот я уже 2 теоретических [случая](http://rsdn.org/article/db/deadlocks.xml) знаю (с X и S локами на 1 одной таблице) какие могут быть проблемы, но я их смогу распознать когда мне описывают поочередность действий двух транзакций.

Что мне пришло на ум:
Подход №1 заново включить профайлер с отслеживанием таких запросов, поймать deadlock, а потом в нем по некоторым идентификаторам(возможно дескрипторам ) найти эти транзакции в записях профайлера, из этого понять какая у транзакций была последовательность. Последовательность действий даст возможность сопоставить текущую ситуацию с известными мне теоретическими вариантами. Если будет совпадение - успех. 
Подход №2 сопоставить SQL код транзакций с кодом приложения которое их генерирует, таким образом понять последовательность выполнения. Далее аналогично варианту 1.

Возможно есть варианты более удобные.

PS. Если на глаз понятно в чем проблема не буду против узнать.

Answer (score 0):

1. Аssociated objid - поле hobt_id представления `sys.partitions`, по нему можно выяснить какая таблица и какой индекс был задействован. Как-то так, например:

   ```
   SELECT OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS TableName,
       i.name AS IndexName
   FROM sys.partitions p
       JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = p.object_id
           AND i.index_id = p.index_id
   WHERE hobt_id = 281474977890304
   ```

Почему у разных транзакций один один и тот же объект? Ну, очевидно, потому что они к нему обратились, что, собственно, и привело к блокировке и, как итог, к дедлоку.

> Вопрос возник потому что если рассматривать эти 2 ресурса как разные
>   ресурсы - не понятно почему грохнули именно ту транзакцию.

Эти ресурсы не нужно рассматривать как разные. А грохается транзакция, которая работала меньше всего. Крайний SELECT стартовал последним, поэтому был выбран жертвой.

2. Нет смысла анализировать граф, имхо. Анализировать стоит XML - там вся информация по всем задействованным процессам. Поменяйте расширение XDL на XML или просто откройте файл в текстовом редакторе.

Comment: "грохается транзакция, которая работала меньше всего" - нууу, не совсем так. Убивается та которая записала меньше в лог.

Comment: Там еще дедлок приорити задействован, на самом деле, ну да, при одинаковом приоритете убьют процесс, который дешевле откатить.

Comment: Просто в XML, как правило, это на глазок можно определить по waittime и, пожалуй, во всех виданных мной случаях жертва была с меньшим waittime.

Comment: Псевдокод который генерирует запросы: foreach(list) { Select; Update; }